# Is it possible to declare C# object reference parameter inline within a method call?

Tags: c#

I have a C# application. I was wondering if there was anyway I can initialize a ref object parameter inline?

**Consider the following code block:**

```
public class CacheTest : Dictionary<string, string> { }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CacheTest cache = null;

    for (int index = 1; index <= 2; index++)
    {
        var result1 = TestClass.DoSomething(ref cache, $"key{index}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Key: {index}  Value{result1}");
    }
}

public static class TestClass
{
    public static string DoSomething(ref CacheTest cache, string key)
    {
        if (cache == null)
        {
            cache = new CacheTest()
            {
                { "key1", "value1" },
                { "key2", "value2" }
            };
        }

        return cache[key];
    }
}
```

In the preceding code block, I am declaring the variable **cache** before I reference it as a ref in the **DoSomething()** method call.

Is there any way that I can do this in a single line either through use of ref or out?

**Something like this:**

```
var result1 = TestClass.DoSomething(ref CacheTest cache, $"key{index}")
```

I know it's a stretch, but I've got to make changes to existing code in a 100 places and it would nice to provide a tighter implementation. I would want to initialize only on the 1st call.

Comment: Have you considered the Fundamental Theorem of Computer Science(tm) here? Rather than try to do this with ref, why not abstract your cache inside another class, pass that class reference to DoSomething, and have DoSomething check the cache member to see if it's null? Or better yet lazily construct the cache member in a property of the wrapping class?

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a ref parameter inline is not possible, but declaring an out parameter inline is. Instead of doing:

```
Cache? c = null;
DoSomething(ref c);
```

You can do:

```
DoSomething(out var c);
```

Instead of initializing through references, you should use a design pattern or stick with constructors. You could even just construct the cache inside of the method and return it since it's a reference type anyways unless it's a struct.

Here's a link to an MSDN article that brings up its idealized usage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/performance/